# Map Function to Dictionary of Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a networked game where I am constantly looping over a game object dictionary to call one function on them, for example draw or send_location or get location. I am looking for a way to improve it. I would like to be able to call a function, that accepts a function as an argument, and that function is then called on each game object. Sometimes the function is a class method of each object, which makes it a little difficult. Here is what I have so far. The game object dictionary has a structure like game_objects = {'players':[player1, player2], 'other_objects':[object1, object2]}

```
def loop_over_game_dict(self, func, *args):
  """looop over the game dictionary and apply function with the arguments to
  all objects"""
  for obj_type, obj_list in self.game_objects.items():
    for game_obj in obj_list:
        # apply some function with the current game object as the first parameter
        func(game_object, *args)
```

For example, if I want a function that builds a game packet

```
def send_location(self, game_obj, packet ):
  packet[game_obj.id] = packet.serialize(game_obj.rect.x, game_obj.rect.y)

# somewhere in the code
loop_over_game_dict(send_location, packet_object)
```

My question is how is something like this done in other games if at all? I feel like I am constantly looping over objects in the game to do one thing(collision detection, rendering) and this would make it a lot simpler. Is looping over them all the time represent a flaw in my design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what this question has to do with your game's code in particular but...

Explicit looping over a set of objects is not, in general, a design flaw (although there are some cases like CPU-bound math where it may not be the fastest solution):

```
results = []
for obj in input:
    results.append( func(obj) )
```

However, if you find this to be needlessly verbose, Python also offers at least *two* other ways to do the above in a single-line form.

List comprehension:

```
results = [ func(obj) for obj in input ]
```

Or the `map` function, which is borrowed/inspired by  functional programming languages:

```
results = map(func, obj)
```

Comment: List comprehension, I knew of it, but didn't think to use it here. Thanks!